# Can Lucy still call her Celestial Spirits?

Tags: fairy-tail

After the time skip, Lucy gained the new magic "Star Dress" that allows Lucy to have the power of her Celestial Spirits.

But is she still able to call her Celestial Spirits as she did before?

I haven't watched the entire anime series, I just read the manga. Did I forget or miss something about Lucy's Celestial Spirits?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes you forgot about a few events. She summoned both Virgo and the Star Dress, Virgo Form in chapter 427 for example.

[image]

Other examples are:

- Chapter 422 where she summoned both Leo and his dress
- Chapter 431 where she summoned both Taurus and his dress

It seems that she always summons a dress and doesn't want to rely on the spirits alone any more, but she can still summon them. Seeing as she can summon two spirits at the same time (maybe more by now), she can also summon both the dress and a spirit and I'm assuming she can even summon both the dress of one spirit and another spirit at the same time. I don't think they must be related.

Comment: oh yes! I'm forget about that Lucy and summon Virgo and also her dress. I remember now, if I'm not mistaken when she summon Taurus and his dress when fight against Avatar right?